# Laravel 5.4 Mail test

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.4

Sounds simple enough but I cannot work out how to pass data to the below mailable for a test. It works fine for normal use.

**Working, through controller**

```
Mail::to($user)->send(new C2cMail($this->commitment->data, \App\EModule::findOrFail($this->commitment->module_id), $user));
```

**Mailable**

```
    public function __construct($commitment, Module $module, User $user)
    {
        $this->commitment = unserialize($commitment);
        $this->module = $module;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->title = $this->module->title;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        try {
            if(empty(env('MAIL_FROM')) || !env('MAIL_FROM') || env('MAIL_FROM') == null){
                throw new \Exception("You must set your MAIL_FROM environment variable", 406);
            }
            $this->from(env('MAIL_FROM'))->subject('First email test')->view('mail.c2c-1');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

So this all works fine but I cannot get a unit test to pass data to the mailable constructor.

**Test case**

```
public function testC2cEmailSend()
    {
        Mail::fake();

        // Grab any old C2C entry
        $c2c = \App\Commitment::with(['module', 'user'])->first();

        $data = $c2c->data;
        $user = $c2c->user;
        $module = $c2c->module;
        $mailable_data = ['data' => $data, 'user' => $user, 'module' => $module];

        Mail::assertSent(C2cFirst::class, function($mail) use ($mailable_data) {
            return $mail->hasTo($mailable_data['user']->email);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Self resolved**

It was a misunderstanding on how `Mail::fake()` actually works. It hijacks the `Mail` class and replaces it with an instance of `MailFake`; and so placing it above the desired functionality prevents actual sending.

Comment: Mail::fake() does not test it there is a problem inside email. Mailable->build() is never executed and email- blade is never build.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Correct

Comment: then it should be not the "mail test" question, but rather "Mocking Mail test" question.

Comment: Well I don't keep a diary, this question is more than two years old and you're splitting hairs about a problem I no longer care about.